# CSS rotated text displayed under icons

Tags: html, css, rotation

I want to rotate a text between several icons. When I use CSS rotate, the text is "over" the icons.

Original appearance:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 traindir">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up traindir-arrow"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up traindir-arrow"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up traindir-arrow"></i>
    <div class="traindir-text">Färdriktning</div>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up traindir-arrow"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up traindir-arrow"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up traindir-arrow"></i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.traindir {
  margin-top: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.traindir-text {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform-origin: center center 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center 0;
  transform-origin: center center 0;
}
```

After I rotate, I get this:

[image]

I guess that you can see the problem, I want the arrows above the text, not covering it. I tried changing properties for display, height and width in the CSS but that didnt help. Do you have any solution?

Comment: check this link:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform

Answer (score 0):

`writing-mode` ([**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)) might be an option here.

**VIEW DEMO FULL SCREE**N

```css
.traindir {
  font-size: 20px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 traindir">

  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> 
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
  <span class="traindir-text">Färdriktning</span>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> 
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the rotation is necessary (and the arrow **down**) as the rl/lr does not reverse the direction here